# How do I merge multiple outlook pst files?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007

My computer had some trouble and I gave it to someone to fix it which they did but in the process they completely messed up outlook.

They somehow managed to delete my entire record which I had running since 2007. I think then they panicked and started taking multiple backups (.pst's) which are now scattered all over my computer.

The existing outlook now has just a part of what it originally had - messages, notes and contacts. I think the rest of it are in the backup .pst files.

Some of these backup files are huge ~ 20-25GB and when I try to import then one by one it results in lot of duplicates.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft doesn't have an official tool to merge PST files. You have to import back one by one. When you import PST files to Outlook, you can select "Replace duplicates with items imported"

[image]

Reference:[Import email, contacts, and calendar from an Outlook .pst file](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-email-contacts-and-calendar-from-an-outlook-pst-file-431a8e9a-f99f-4d5f-ae48-ded54b3440ac)